# TabControl Navigation Buttons / Determine if Tab is Visible

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I am trying to add tabcontrol navigation buttons like Notepad++ has.

I am using Firemonkey in Delphi-XE8.

[image: notepad++]

I first must determine if all tabs are visible.

So here is the form:

[image: formwithtabs]

And if i resize it the third tab is gone:

[image: formwithouttab]

Things i tried that didn't work to check if a tab is visible:

```
TabItem1.IsVisible

TabControl1.FindVisibleTab(2, TTabControl.TFindKind.Current)

TabControl1.FindVisibleTab(TTabControl.TFindKind.Last)
```

Or maybe someone knows a better way to implement tabcontrol buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT good solution, based only on my experience

1st way set "TTabControl.FullSize" to True, but this will change how your TabControl looks

[image]

2nd way even worse, because it's "dog-nail" aka "cruke solution"

```
if TabControl1.Tabs[2].AbsoluteMatrix.m32 = 65535 then
  begin
    { TAB NOT VISIBLE }
  end
else
  begin
    { TAB VISIBLE }
  end;
```